# How to embed interop types from ADODB?

Tags: .net, com, ado, adodb

My COM class located in .NET assembly foo.dll is building `ADODB.Recordset` from .NET `IDataReader` and then returning it back to caller, in my case classic ASP legacy page. However, we identified performance bottleneck which seems to be the call to `new ADODB.Recordset()` and we found out setting `Embed interop types` on adodb.dll greatly improves the performance. Unfortunately, this causes an exception in classic ASP:

```
System.TypeLoadException: Could not load type 'ADODB.FieldsToInternalFieldsMarshaler' from assembly 'foo ...'.
  at System.StubHelpers.StubHelpers.CreateCustomMarshalerHelper(IntPtr pMD, Int32 paramToken, IntPtr hndManagedType)
  at ADODB._Recordset.get_Fields()
```

Various pages says that remediation for this issue is to NOT embed interop types from adodb.dll, but performance then goes south... Performance improvements were verified by using another .NET app referencing foo.dll with embedded adodb.dll versus not embedded. Also, how comes our tests .NET app can work with foo.dll with embedded interop types, but classic ASP cannot? Thanks for any advice.

**EDIT:**

Performance issue was tracked down to compiler ouput when embedding vs not embedding interop types from adodb.dll. Repro:

1. Create new c# library,
2. Add reference to adodb.dll
3. Mark it as `Embed interop types` false
4. Add code and compile:

   ```
   using System;

   namespace cax_test
   {
       public class Class1
       {
           public static ADODB.Recordset Get()
           {
               return new ADODB.Recordset();
           }
       }
   }
   ```
5. Open resulting dll in e.g. ILSpy and observe the `ADODB.Recordset` constructor got rewritten to:

   ```
   return new ADODB.RecordsetClass();
   ```
6. Change `Embed interop types` to true and recompile
7. Open in ILSpy again and observe now the constructor is:

   ```
   return (ADODB.Recordset)Activator.CreateInstance(Marshal.GetTypeFromCLSID(new Guid("00000535-0000-0010-8000-00AA006D2EA4")));
   ```

While referencing such assembly from console app and calling `Class1.Get()` method 1000x doesnt make difference, referencing it from web app and doing the same makes version with `RecordsetClass` multiple times slower than the one with `CreateInstance`. Example of such app to be hosted in IIS can be downloaded from [here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=113Baj9a4mSQEpH7xNF6Omt0OySOmHUZX), then just hit http://localhost/test_app/t2.ashx and observe difference between activator vs constructor version. To see the implementation of cax_test.dll's methods, just open it in ILSpy, it looks like this:

```
using ADODB;
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace cax_test
{
    public class Class1
    {
        public static Recordset GetViaActivator()
        {
            return (Recordset)Activator.CreateInstance(Marshal.GetTypeFromCLSID(new Guid("00000535-0000-0010-8000-00AA006D2EA4")));
        }

        public static Recordset GetViaConstructor()
        {
            return new RecordsetClass();
        }
    }
}
```

For me the measured times are:

```
activator: 00:00:00.1475626
constructor: 00:00:01.3152554
```

Comment: No, I don't believe for a second that using ADODB with COM interop has better performance than using ADO.NET or a managed ORM framework.

Comment: @rory.ap where in my question am I saying that? I am saying that creating an instance of adodb.recordset seems faster when adodb.dll interoperability types are embedded into foo.dll.

Comment: The performance change between the two configurations is unexpected. I would focus on that before anything else (when does it happen? during connection? command execute?). I can't reproduce neither this nor the get_Fields error. Do you have a reproducing code of some sort?

Comment: @SimonMourier for the error to reproduce you would need to create and register COM object foo.dll which has a method creating `ADODB.Recordset` and call this method from classic asp page. With perf problem example, I ll get back to it hopefully later in the evening to provide an example.

Comment: @SimonMourier hmm, I wanted to create repro for the performance issue at home, but using win10 and iis10 to host my web app it doesnt happen, wlthough at work using server 2012 and iis 7.5 it does.. Seems like IIS is to blame, have to confirm.

Comment: Even with IIS, It's difficult to imagine a reason for big performance issues between embedded types vs external types. For .NET, they're just metadata that help define binary contracts (COM interfaces, guids, enums, mostly). I mean, you can have some (small) performance issue loading an external DLL, but this would be a one time penalty.

Comment: I hate to say it, but if this was causing me pain, I'd be looking at simply removing all that legacy COM overhead completely - by the pragmatic approach of just replacing it with ADO.NET code (perhaps making use of tools like EF or Dapper to avoid `DataTable`). Unless you have *significant* volumes of legacy code, I can't see any advantage in continuing to fight that dragon

Comment: @SimonMourier I was finally able to put down the repro, please see EDIT section. It boils down to compiler differences when embedding interop types.

Comment: @MarcGravell yes, I would love to move to ADO.NET, but unfortunately our app is ~ 2 millions lines of ASP code.

Comment: Time to think outside the box a bit.  Classic ASP is quite capable of using ADODB by itself.  It already does to make this code work.  It just does not need you to help provide the Fields reference, it can do it by itself when you give it a RecordSet.  Cuts out the custom marshaler and any wonky perf suspicion.

Comment: @HansPassant Thanks, unfortunately old ODBC driver doesnt support TLS 1.2, therefore we need to switch to .NET and provide recordsets back to ASP. And no, upgrading to new ODBC driver is not an option, as it doesnt work with nvarchar(max) columns, just silently trims them.

Comment: I never mentioned ODBC, ADODB is the same everywhere.  Very strange requirement in the first place, surely your back-end is not the Internet?

Comment: @HansPassant to make it clearer, we are retrieving data from sql db using ODBC driver together with ADODB.Connection, ADODB.Recordset etc. This has to change in order to support TLS1.2. The requirement didnt come from me, from what I was told it is in order to be PCI compliant or something of that sort.

Comment: Ok, so you're talking about object creation. I do see a difference with your repro, but it's far from being 10x like you, it's more 50% (x1.5). Which BTW I don't understand anyway since the count of registry accesses with "constructor" is like 3X less then whith "activator". In console, I do observe exactly the opposite performance which seems logicial but again like 1.5x ratio. For info, I've tested IIS, IISExpress, both in x86 and x64 mode, Release vs Debug. You could try to use procmon during your test (like I did). See if you get something really weird.

Comment: If you're really after object creation performance, I suggest you replace your existing code by a code similar to this: https://pastebin.com/A0e8FZB6 it should be much faster, and it's independent from Embed interop type configuration.